# Zipping up individual files gets stuck in loop

Tags: zip

I am trying to zip up a shapefile. I have selected all the components of the shapefile bar the LOCK and .CPG files. These cant be uploaded on our website for some reason, and cause a problem.

I have tried using the following code, but its keeps getting stuck in a loop and crashes. I have a seperate folder which can be zipped up quite easily using the shutil method. However, as im trying to identify files to zip, I have to use the Zipfile module.

```
rtc_shp = r"path/to/shp

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(datafolder, "Real_Time_Closures.zip"), "w")

for f in glob.glob(rtc_shp.replace(".shp",".*")):
    if not f.endswith(".lock"):
        if not f.endswith(".cpg"):
            zip.write(f, basename(f))

shutil.make_archive(indivfolder, "zip", indivfolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed the loop by creating an empty list and then appending the filenames to the list. I then wrote the contents of the list to the zip file.

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(datafolder, "MMO_Real_Time_Closures.zip"), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

shp_zip_list = []

for f in glob.glob(rtc_shp.replace(".shp",".*")):
    if not f.endswith(".lock"):
        if not f.endswith(".cpg"):
            shp_zip_list.append(f)

for f in shp_list:
    zip.write(f, basename(f))

zip.close()

shutil.make_archive(indivfolder, "zip", indivfolder)
```